# php regex doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

this is my string

```
$var = 'foo<ul class="foo"> test </ul>foo<ul class="bar">foo</ul><ul></ul>foo';
```

this is my regex

```
/<ul[^>]*>.*?<\/ul>/g
```

this is my code

```
$var = preg_replace('/<ul[^>]*>.*?<\/ul>/', 'bar', $var);
```

i want to replace all ul elements to bar so after this code my string should look like this

```
foo barfoo bar barfoo
```

It works in regex101.com perfectly, but doesn't replace anyting in php
Any ideas what's wrong with my code or regex?

//edit
After answers, I tried this and worked then I realized my original string had newlines in it.
So I changed my regex to this and it works now

```
/<ul[^>]*>(.|\r|\n)*?<\/ul>/g
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: DO NOT! EVER! Try to use Regex to Parse HTML

Comment: What's wrong? you're using regexes on html. What you want would be better done with a DOM parser, and more reliably to boot.

Comment: Your code seems to work here: https://eval.in/241762

Comment: Where are the spaces in your output string coming from?  regex101.com gives me `foobarfoobarbarfoo`.

Comment: This works fine, except for the missing spaces

Comment: Works fine for me. Just put a space before the 'bar' in the preg_replace. Do you know what version of PHP you are using?

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1188035)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had those code tested and it turned out OK:

```
$var = 'foo<ul class="foo"> test </ul>foo<ul class="bar">foo</ul><ul></ul>foo';
$var = preg_replace('/<ul[^>]*>.*?<\/ul>/', 'bar', $var);
echo $var;
```

please try it.

Comment: in addition, the "g" modifier is not supported in PHP;
LINK:http://php.net/manual/zh/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: This is exactly the same code as he has given. And we established in the comments that his code worked!

Answer (score -1):

To get the result as you mentioned in your question `foo barfoo bar barfoo` try following

```
<?php

$var = 'foo<ul class="foo"> test </ul>foo<ul class="bar">foo</ul><ul></ul>foo';
$var = preg_replace('/<ul[^>]*>.*?<\/ul>/', ' bar', $var);
echo $var;

?>
```

I added a space in replace string ' bar'

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not understand, what was the point of this question, and do not understand a -1 on my answer which exactly addressed the question asked. Ridiculous indeed.